# Maven: java package does not exist

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I was working on this project for months, all was fine and well.  One day I open the project and suddenly maven doesn't recognize ANY of its dependencies.  I have been endlessly searching for an answer online but came across nothing that has helped.

I have tried several things: `mvn clean install`, I deleted the project and pulled it from git.  Sometimes it will work for a couple compiles, but after that it gives me the same exact errors.  This has been giving me a headache and have been trying to fix it for a couple days now but am exhausted trying to find things that will fix this.  Has anyone had this problem before?  Again, the same project has been working fine for months except for one day where I open it up and decide to work on it, Maven gives me errors similar to: `Error: package doesn't exist`

After a couple successful compiles, it will show me about ~100 similar errors to this next time I try and compile the application again: `Error:(4, 26) java: package com.amazonaws.auth does not exist`

pom.xml file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <!-- Use latest version whenever available -->
    <jackson.version>2.9.4</jackson.version>
    <aws.version>1.11.295</aws.version>
    <apache.commons.version>2.6</apache.commons.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${aws.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kinesisvideo</artifactId>
        <version>${aws.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kinesisvideo -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kinesisvideo</artifactId>
        <version>${aws.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-producer</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-cbor</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.commons.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scream3r/jssc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scream3r</groupId>
        <artifactId>jssc</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openpnp/opencv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: What's the exact error message? And does it only happen with this project, or with others as well? Did anything change in your `settings.xml`?

Comment: Sometimes right click on project->maven->reimport may help.

Comment: It's also possible the internal cache of IntelilJ got corrupted. You can invalidate the cache and restart. It will re-index everything when it restarts and that may help too sometimes.

Comment: @Pablo Yea I tried all of that, reimporting, re-downloading, everything. @Pim Hazebroek Tried, no luck :/
@SeverityOne And I am getting numerous errors, but all of the same class.  These are what they look like.

`Error:(29, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AWSStaticCredentialsProvider
  location: class com.mbessler.droneapp.aws.AWSUser`

and

`Error:(12, 39) java: package com.amazonaws.services.s3.model does not exist`

Comment: Does the issue occure with other Maven projects? Does it compile fine using "mvn compile" from Maven Tool window or command line? Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after running "Reimport"?